# How to do a query with a two-value range and a scope, with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get the results between two values in Rails. I am using scope in model. My model is like the following:

```
# Model ad.rb
scope :min_price, -> (number) { "ads.price = #{number}%" }
scope :max_price, -> (number) { "ads.price = #{number}%" }
```

And this is my controller

```
# Controller ads_controller.rb
def index
   @ads = Ad.where((min_price(params[:min_price]))..(max_price(params[:max_price]))).order("created_at DESC") if params[:min_price].present? if params[:max_price].present? 
end
```

This does not work. What's the right way?

Comment: You force equality of `price` to two different values simultaneously, one in each scope. Resulting set of conditions never evaluates to true abd thus no rows match. What are you expecting, magic? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should combine them when using them together, otherwise you will have one overwrite the other (depending on how you call them in the query).

```
class Ad
  scope :min_max_price ->(min,max) { where('price > ? AND price < ?', min, max) }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Or to do it separately:

```
class Ad
  scope :min_price, ->(min) { where('price > ?', min) }
  scope :max_price, ->(max) { where('price < ?', max) }
end

class AdController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @ads = Ad.min_price(params[:min]).max_price(params[:max])
  end
end
```

Scopes are designed to be chained, not included in the args to a where list. In particular, when you call `where` ActiveRecord returns a relation object that corresponds to the query. When you chain off of it with `where`, `limit`, `order`, etc, it creates a new Relation object that is the combination of the chained methods.

When you finally access an object of the collection with something like `all` or `each`, that's when the actual query is constructed and sent on to the database.